# ¿Cómo puedo saber si el player de YouTube está mostrando un anuncio?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He estado intentando ver si el reproductor de videos de YouTube está mostrando un anuncio, para poder asegurarme de que mi extensión de navegador (con WebExtensions) no es usada para "evitar anuncios", mi código actual es

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
    if ($("#movie_player").hasClass("ad-interrupting")) {
          console.log("Anuncio")
    }
}, 
10000);
```

Estoy intentando ver si la clase ad-interrupting existe, porque después de ver de cerca que clases tiene el reproductor, me di cuenta de que esta clase se añadía siempre que había un anuncio.
El problema es que siempre devuelve un valor `false`, aunque la clase si exista, como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Probablemente este ocurriendo que la clase a la que apuntas llamada `"ad-interrupting"` sea añadida por medio de un script externo que tardara un rato en cargar y añadirle la clase al elemento, de todas maneras eso que dices de `devolver` no aplica para un `setInterval`, es decir... se que a lo mejor no es en el `setInterval` donde intentas devolver si efectivamente hay un anuncio o no, pero entonces nos estamos perdiendo de informacion relevante, es decir, donde estas retornando algun valor?, el codigo que muestras no nos dice nada respecto a lo que intentas arreglar.

Comment: Esto lo digo porque como te digo en un setInterval no tiene sentido retornar nada, almenos que lo tengas almacenado de alguna forma. y de todas maneras segun tu codigo, no estas retornando nada.

Comment: Con lo que me referia con devolver, es que al crear un console.log con el hasClass, este siempre decia false aunque la clase si estuviera